# How to integrate a custom learner (not available in any R package) in mlr pipeline

Tags: r, mlr

I have created following learner using mlr in R

```
makeRLearner.classif.dt_c4_5 = function() {
  makeRLearnerClassif(
    cl = "classif.dt_c4_5",
    package = "dtc45",
    par.set = makeParamSet(
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "max_depth", default = 5L, lower = 1L),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "min_obs", default = 20L, lower = 1L),
      makeDiscreteLearnerParam(id = "lr_run", default = 0L, values = 0:1),
      ),
    properties = c("twoclass", "numerics", "factors", "prob"),
    name = "Decision Tree",
    short.name = "dt_c4_5",
    note = "C4.5 Implementation of Decision Tree",
    callees = c("dt_C4_5_model")
  )
}

#' @export
trainLearner.classif.dt_c4_5 = function(.learner, .task, .subset, .weights = NULL, ...) {
  d = getTaskData(.task, .subset)
  f = getTaskFormula(.task)
  dtc45::dt_C4_5_model(f, data = d, ...)
}

#' @export
predictLearner.classif.dt_c4_5 = function(.learner, .model, .newdata, ...) {
  type = switch(.learner$predict.type == "prob", "class")
  predict(.model$learner.model, newdata = .newdata, type = type, ...)
}
```

But while calling makeLearner method of this function,

```
dt_c4_5_prob <- makeLearner('classif.dt_c4_5', predict.type="prob",
                            max_depth = 5,
                            min_obs = 50,
                            lr_run = 0)
```

I get the following error -

```
 Error in makeParamSet(makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "max_depth", default = 5L,  : 
  argument is missing, with no default
```

How can i integrate such learner in mlr?

Comment: Did you register the S3 methods? See https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html

Comment: yeah, i have registered all three S3 methods as explained in the link you posted.

Comment: You've got a stray comma at the end of the line defining the last parameter.